# display comma separated names as in list in p:datatable column

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using p:datatable, my third column is grouped names which is comma separated string, I want to show it as list(one name in one row)currently its showing comma separated which looks ugly

```
<p:dataTable value="#{itemRelationshipBean.itemRelationshipDTO}" var="itemRelationship" >
<p:column headerText="default name">#{itemRelationship.defaultItemName}</p:column>
<p:column headerText="relationship name">#{itemRelationship.relationshipName}</p:column>
<p:column headerText="grouped item names">#{itemRelationship.groupedItems}</p:column>
</p:column>
```

implemented comma separated string to list

```
public List<String> toList(String groupNames){
List<String> grpList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(groupNames.split(",")));

return grpList;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i missunderstand you, then sorry!.

in your Bean, you can implement a method which takes this comma seperated String as Parameter, and returns a list, then you can iterate over the list using **ui:repeat** or *datatable*, or **c:forEach** components. something like this:

```
<p:column headerText="grouped item names">

    <ui:repeat var="itemName" value="#{itemRelationshipBean.toList(itemRelationship.groupedItems)}">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block"><h:outputText value="#{itemName}"></h:panelGroup>
    </ui:repeat>


</p:column>
```

Comment: it just showing list without comma but no logic to print next item in next row

Comment: @SuryaMandal: the attribute layout="block" of the panelGroup produce a div element. the default display style property of div elements is block. but to ensure line breaks, you can add style="display: block;" to the panelGroup ot to the outputText